# How do you display "%5d" in C?

Tags: c

How do you display the string "%5d" in C? I tried putting a backslash in front of the percent, but it won't print (and gave warnings). I tried Googling but to no avail. I guess this is too wide for me to find a specific answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int test = 40;
    printf("\%5.1d %5.1d", test); //this is the one
    printf("%5.1d", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To print `%` try `printf("%%")`;

This works

```
printf("%%5.1d %5.1d", test);
```

Comment: @CyberMew: If that answer worked for you and helped you out, you should 'Accept' it, meaning that your question is answered. You can do that by clicking the green check mark in the answer box.

Answer (score 2):

Use double % - `printf("%%5d")`.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other two (at least) perfectly correct answers, you could also use `fputs()` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int test = 40;
    fputs("%5d ", stdout);
    printf("%5.1d\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that I added a newline to the output; that is important as the output is not flushed to the terminal until you output a newline.  Note too that I used `fputs()` and not `puts()` because `puts()` emits a newline that you do not want emitted.

However, knowing the general solution of using double-`%` for a real percent in both the `printf()` and `scanf()` families of functions will stand you in good stead for the future.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could do `printf("%s", "%5d")` :) I understand this is kind of roundabout way, and ones described in other answers are better, but just mentioning this is a possibility too.