# How does an invalid escape sequence behave in C?

Tags: c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("\%\n");
    int x = 10;
    printf("\%d\n", x);
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

10

(The first line is not printing)
So what is being done by the escape sequence? If it does not read a % after \, it should not have printed 10 in the second printf statement.

Comment: The correct escape sequence for a literal `%` is `%%`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you display "%5d" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772598/how-do-you-display-5d-in-c)

Comment: @dvnrrs `%%` is not an escape sequence, it is a _conversion specifier_ and unique to the printf family of functions. Unlike escape sequences, which are universal to all C strings (such as `\n`).

Comment: @Lundin You are correct, but "escape sequence" is a very general term and certainly still applies here. `%%` is how `printf` allows one to *escape* from the normal interpretation of `%` as a conversion character. But yes, it is not the same *type* of escape sequence as `\n`. Let's not be too pedantic.

Comment: @dvnrrs The difference is that "escape sequence" is a term formally defined by the C standard and the compiler will check them and ensure that they are correct. Conversion specifiers however, is something specific to the library stdio.h and generally evaluated in runtime. So there are no guarantees that the compiler performs any form of check on conversion specifiers. The answer by glglgl below is a good one, which points out the differences.

Comment: @Lundin I understand the differences completely. Frankly I don't care that the C standard defines "escape sequence"; it is a general term which I used correctly in that context.

Answer (score 3):

`\%` is not a valid escape sequence. Your compiler should raise a warning like

```
[Warning] unknown escape sequence: '\%' [enabled by default]
```

You need `%%` to print `%` otherwise it may or may not be printed.

Comment: It may or may not be printed.

Comment: @RagingScallion; Umm... I don't know about that.

Answer (score 3):

There are two levels of processing here:

1. The parsing of string literals. This is where the `\` becomes effective. `\n` is replaced by the newline character, and other escaping happens as well.
2. The `printf()` mechanism. This one only deals with the `%` as special character, and parses whatever comes after it in order to format one of its arguments.

With `\%` you intermix these two, whatever happens on the `\` (if the `%` is suppressed or not), (2) won't notice the `\` as it is "eaten up" by (1).